# Django Form Validation with Javascript

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

How can I validate a form in Django template using JavaScript dynamically  on the client-side, without going to the server? I am creating the form using the below code:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.field.required %}
        <span style="color:red;" class = "shiva">*</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        <span class="dropt" style="color:red;"> {{ field.label_tag }}:<span >{{field.errors.0}}</span></span> {{ field }}
    {% else %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }} 
    {% endif %}
```

In the JS I want to check whether the field is required or not. If it is required then check whether data was entered or not. If enter ok, else raise an alert. If all required fields are filled then only allow to call the url from the form.

Comment: Bear in mind that JS only validates clientside.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryied this?
From https://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-forms/

```
 {% load ajax_form_utils %}
<form method="post">
  <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('form').validation({% render_ajax_fields form %});
    });
</script>
```